# how to replace all occurances of strings(varies) between strings(which are made of special characters like #,$ ..) in java

Tags: java, string

i need to replace/remove all the strings between "&#" and ';' including the open("&#") and close(";") strings in java, for the string below i need the resultant string be like hello everyone good morning

```
 String Str="hello &#2340;&#2367;&#2352; everyone &#2369;&#2346;&#2340;&#2367; good Morning"
```

tq in advance

Comment: can you show the code you have you tried

Comment: `str.replaceAll("&#.*;", "")`

Comment: Dont give use pseudo code. Give us the code you are currently working with. It just works so much better when *you* start **first**, instead of coming here and asking others to do the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: What could be in between those markers? Would something like `"&#ab&#c;d;;"`  or `"&#ab;cd;"` be possible and if so what should the result be? Or would those portions actually be emojis or some kind of other markup, e.g. would you be interested in the text between `&#` and `;`?

Comment: thank you @YCF_L , but what if str="hello &#2340;&#2367; everyone &#2340;&#2367; goodmorning"; the result would be "hello goodmorning"; i need it to be "hello everyone goodmorning" , i forgot to mention it before.

Comment: @IronFist in this case use `"&#.*?;"`

Comment: thank you verymuch @YCF_L and where can i learn this concept in full

Comment: @IronFist May I ask *why* you want to remove these characters? These codes (`&#...;`) look like *XML Character Entities*, and may contain text in another script. For example, the decoded text within your example is तिरुपति, which is in the Hindi script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)` method in `String` class. 
Here `regex` is the regular expression of the value you need to replace and the `replacement` is the value that you need to replace for the particular regular expression.

```
String str="hello everyone &#2340;&#2367;&#2352;&#2369;&#2346;&#2340;&#2367; goodMorning";
str = str.replaceAll("&#.*;", "");
```

and output will be,

```
hello everyone  goodMorning
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
static final Pattern PAT = Pattern.compile("&#(.*?);");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "hello everyone &#2340;&#2367;&#2352;&#2369;&#2346;&#2340;&#2367; goodMorning";
    String output = PAT.matcher(input)
        .replaceAll(m -> Character.toString(Integer.parseInt(m.group(1))));
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

output:

```
hello everyone तिरुपति goodMorning
```